# Docker command runs successfully from Docker run, but not when using CMD in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, keycloak, bitnami, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am wrapping the Bitnami/Keycloak-Gatekeeper Docker image in a Dockerfile, and trying to run:

```
FROM bitnami/keycloak-gatekeeper:latest
COPY config.yml /opt/bitnami/keycloak-gatekeeper/config.yml
CMD ["/keycloak-gatekeeper --config /opt/bitnami/keycloak-gatekeeper/config.yml"]
```

This gives an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/keycloak-gatekeeper --config /opt/bitnami/keycloak-gatekeeper/config.yml\": stat /keycloak-gatekeeper --config /opt/bitnami/keycloak-gatekeeper/config.yml: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

However, when I run this using a docker run command, everything executes as expected.

```
docker run -v "config.yml:/opt/bitnami/keycloak-gatekeeper/config.yml" bitnami/keycloak-gatekeeper:latest /keycloak-gatekeeper --config /opt/bitnami/keycloak-gatekeeper/config.yml
```

Why does this work directly through docker run, and not within the Dockerfile?

How can I solve this issue so that I can run using the Dockerfile?

Comment: Your `docker run` command is different: your shell breaks it up into multiple "words", but the JSON-array `CMD` form has it all as one "word".  You need to manually specify each word in the `CMD [...]`, or use the shell-form `CMD /keycloak-gatekeeper ...` without the square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMD ["keycloak-gatekeeper", "--config", "/opt/bitnami/keycloak-gatekeeper/config.yml"]